# CuPY: Not seeing kernel concurrency

Tags: python, cuda, cupy

I'm currently working on parallelizing huge matrix computation using CuPY's RawKernels using async streams.

It seems like each RawKernel call is waiting for prevous kernel to finish eventhough I specify that stream is non-blocking.

[image: Visual profiler]

Does anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a simple example that creates 32 streams. Each stream should copy single slice of 3D input array to 3D output array.

```
import cupy

kernel = cupy.RawKernel(
    '''
    extern "C"
    __global__ void simple_copy(float* iArr, float* oArr, int rows, int cols, int slice){
        unsigned int col = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
        unsigned int row = blockDim.y*blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    
        if(row < rows && col < cols){
//this for loop is just additional work to see kernel launches in visual profiler more easily
            for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
                oArr[rows*cols*slice + row*cols + col] = iArr[rows*cols*slice + row*cols + col];
            }
        }        
    } 
    '''
    , 'simple_copy')


device = cupy.cuda.Device()
# [x, y, z]
iArr1 = cupy.ones((32*32, 32*32, 32), dtype=cupy.float32)
oArr1 = cupy.zeros((32*32, 32*32, 32), dtype=cupy.float32)

n = 32
map_streams = []
for i in range(n):
    map_streams.append(cupy.cuda.stream.Stream(non_blocking=True))

# I want to run kernel on individual z-axis slice asynchronous
for i, stream in enumerate(map_streams):
    with stream:
        kernel((32, 32), (32, 32), (iArr1, oArr1, 32*32, 32*32, i))
device.synchronize()
```

Comment: Each of your kernels will fill the GPU, leaving no room for other kernels to execute.  Therefore they serialize.There is no reason to assume that kernels automatically/always run concurrently. Kernel concurrency requires very specific conditions. You haven't satisfied those conditions. You are launching 1024 blocks each of 1024 threads.  A Tesla V100 can only handle at most 160 of those blocks at a time.There is no reason to assume that some of the blocks of the 2nd kernel will intermingle with the first, and there would be no benefit even if they did. The GPU does not have infinite capacity.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for the insights. In new in CUDA programming and still have a lot of documentation to go through. I tested the same program with smaller array and got the correct "concurrent" behaviour.
Can you post this comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @RobertCrovella could you share how you were able to create the graphical output from your profiler? Cupy's documentation on the matter is still under construction. Thanks.

Comment: @bernard I think you tagged the wrong person.  I didn't create any profiler output here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like each RawKernel call is waiting for prevous kernel to finish eventhough I specify that stream is non-blocking....
> .... Does anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

You are not doing anything wrong, beyond expecting something to happen that is not possible.

Concurrent kernel execution is only possible if there are sufficient resources available to run more than  one kernel at once. All currently supported GPUs have a maximum of 2048 active threads per multiprocessor, and your blocks are 1024 threads each. That means a maximum of two blocks can run per multiprocessor. Depending on the size of your GPU, that means less than roughly 60 blocks could run simultaneously at an absolutely maximum. Given that one kernel launch will "saturate" your GPU capacity many times over, the possibility of a second actually have resources to run is extremely slim. That is why you see no overlap or concurrency between kernel launches.